# capturar valor de outro input com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Galera montei um sisteminha que ao digitar o nome do usuário em um input, o jQuery captura o nome e chama um arquivo php. Que por sua vez faz uma consulta no BD e preenche um select list.

Bom a estrutura esta assim:

```js
function buscar_f_pagamento() {
  var id = $('#cliente').val();
  if (id) {
    var url = 'Busca/Casas.php?id=' + id;
    $.get(url, function(dataReturn) {
      $('#load_f_pagamento').html(dataReturn);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='nome' name="nome" value='1'>

<input name="cliente" id="cliente" onchange="buscar_f_pagamento()">




<select name='casa' id="load_f_pagamento"></select>
```

Bom o que preciso fazer é quando eu chamar o `buscar_f_pagamento` no input `cliente` o valor que tem que ser passado no jQuery tem que ser o do `input` nome

Comment: da mesma forma que recebe o `$("#cliente").val()` você faz com `$("#nome").val()`

Comment: vlw muito obrigado deu certo ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só alterar a linha

```
var id = $('#cliente').val();
```

Para

```
var id = $('#nome').val();
```

> Não se esqueça de definir o type do seu input cliente.

Comment: vlw muito obrigado deu certo ;)